# Is there any option in php.ini to set whether this environment is production or development?

Tags: php, apache, php-5.5

...so that I can write custom logging codes. For example my passwords in production and development environments are different and thus I use `get_cfg_var("mysqli.default_pw")`, so that when I push my code to the production environment I don't need to edit the password.

I need production-development setting because I want always to show logging when in production environment, and I want to show logging to my static IP when in development environment. (by logging I mean SQL query in JSON response, and some other minor things).

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing in php.ini*, but you can do that simply by [setting an environment variable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv):

```
SetEnv MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT production
```

Put this into your core Apache (virtual) host configuration file, or into an .htaccess file, depending on what you have access to.

In PHP then, use [`getenv`](http://php.net/getenv):

```
switch (getenv('MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT')) {
    case 'production':
        ...
    default:
        ...
}
```

In fact, instead of hardcoding different configurations which you `switch` by an environment variable, consider setting necessary configuration through environment variables entirely. Or use that variable to point to a configuration file which you `include` in PHP:

```
require_once (getenv('MYAPP_CONFIG') ?: 'defaults.php');
```

Even better: you have a certain neutral default configuration of which you can selectively override individual parameters via environment variables. I'll leave that up as an exercise to the reader.

As a rule of thumb and design guideline: you shouldn't commit system-specific configuration data into your source code repository.

<sub>* I suppose you *can* add any configuration you want to php.ini, but you shouldn't. That file is a system wide configuration for all PHP instances. What you want really is application/(virtual) host specific, so a flag in Apache is much more appropriate.</sub>